# StaticModel::Base undefined method column_names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a class Region that extended StaticModel::Base. I set data with function

```
set_data_file 'db/static/regions.yml'
```

Yes, I get what I want - I have a static model. And I have a access to my data

```
Region.find(1)
```

It work.

But I need to register this class.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Region do ... end
```

And I have a error - 'undefined method column_names'.
I add a method column_names, from source code ActiveRecord's, but it not resolve problem because then I have a errors (undefined method reorder and so on) I added methods from ActiveRecord until I have error (undefined method ransack).

But when I call my normal objects activerecord I have:

```
City(id: integer, name: string ...)
```

And when I call my class Region I have just

```
Region
```

And I can use only `find` method - and it work.

And when I call Region.first I have:

```
<Region:0x007fc6e35028d0 @attributes={"active"=>true ... }, @id=1>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Hey, I checked out StaticModel::Base. It seemed like it doesn't include ActiveRecord methods in it anyway. The methods it has are defined by the base from the scratch. I wouldn't recommend adding methods from ActiveRecord until it gets fixed. About the ransack method, ActiveAdmin has Ransack in its dependency, and Ransack adds method to ActiveRecord classes. So since StaticModel::Base and ActiveRecord ain't related in anyway, the error is natural.

Comment: And why have you decided to store the data on and retrieve from a yml file ?